# Search result from two different model related by foreign-key

Tags: python, django, django-models

I've two models. One is

```
class Pin(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    def __str__(self):
        return self.title
```

another is

```
class Content(models.Model):
    pin = models.ForeignKey(Pin, on_delete = models.CASCADE)
    content_type = models.CharField(max_length=2)
    content = models.TextField()
```

I want show the list of `Pin`'s if the `Pin`'s `title` or `Content's` `content` contains the search query.

For a single `Pin` there can be multiple `Content`, and I want to show the list of `Pins` if the `title` of `Pin` or  the `content` of a `Content` match.

I can generate result if the Pin's title contains the query. Anyone can help me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

General syntax of filtering is :

`<ModelName>.objects.filter(
      Q(<ForeignKeyField>__<field_name>__<filter_method>=<query>) | 
      Q(<field_name>__<filter_method>=<query>)
      )`

- `|' here is **OR** operator
- `distinct()` is used so that the identical querysets are again filtered in resulting queryset.

```
def get_pin_list(request, q):
    pins = []
    if q:
        querysets = Content.objects.filter(Q(pin__title__icontains=q) |
                                           Q(content__icontains=q)
                                           ).distinct('pin')
        pins = [queryset.pin for queryset in querysets]

    return render(request, 'some_page.html', {'pins': pins})
```

In case if it doesn't works for **MySQL**:

```py
def get_pin_list(request, q):
    pins = []
    if q:
        querysets = Content.objects.filter(Q(pin__title__icontains=q) |
                                           Q(content__icontains=q)
                                           ).distinct()
        pins = [queryset.pin for queryset in querysets]
        pins = list(set(pins))

    return render(request, 'some_page.html', {'pins': pins})
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. may be there is a typing mistakes on `Q(content___icontains=q)` this line. there will be one less underscore. Your code is working but sometimes return duplicate result (Same result twice).

Comment: I'm using mysql and got `DISTINCT ON fields is not supported by this database backend`.

Answer (score 0):

Try this way.

```
 from django.db.models import Q

 query = request.GET.get("q")
    if query:
        queryset_list = Content.objects.filter(
                Q(pin__title__icontains=query)|
                Q(content_type__icontains=query)|
                Q(content__icontains=query) 
                ).distinct()
```